# how to detect if the screen is capacitive or resistive in an Android device?

Tags: android, feature-detection, touchscreen

I am developing an application that will behave slightly different depending on the type of screen. Is there any way to detect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a small trick to do it but requires a canvas. 
Just detecting in a motionEvent if

event.getPressure() > 0 then is capacitive ; event.getSize() > 0 then is resistive

the problem is I dont want to use a canvas just for detecting it :(

Comment: This doesn't work, because capacitive screens that use a stylus report a pressure of 0 as well.

Answer (score 1):

`android.content.res.Configuration` contains a value called `touchscreen`, which could be `TOUCHSCREEN_STYLUS` (=resistive), `TOUCHSCREEN_FINGER` (=capacitive), `TOUCHSCREEN_NOTOUCH` (=no touch screen), `TOUCHSCREEN_UNDEFINED` (=uh oh).

EDIT: I got Dianne'd again :) So - bottom line, it seems like there is no way to get the actual physical properties of the screen. I guess your best bet is to have a setting to allow users to switch between your two modes.

Comment: No that won't work -- that constant means the devices is *designed* to be used with a stylus.  That is, smaller UI elements etc.  This is not currently considered a compatible device, so in practice you will never see this.

Comment: There is a such thing as a capacitive stylus, this will not work.