# Is there any way to check if device supports stylus input?

Tags: android, types, screen

I want to show an menu item only if the device supports the stylus for input.

Unfortunately i've found nothing check if the device or the display supports the stylus/Spen for input.

Edit:
I can distinguish between Stylus and Finger after a MotionEvent is triggered using event.getToolType().
If the tooltype is TOOL_TYPE_STYLUS i can be sure that it supports the stylus.
If not i can guess if there is a pressure > 0 (relating to [how to detect if the screen is capacitive or resistive in an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4294754/1538176))

But i would like to know it in the onCreate method of my activity.

Following is somehow not supported and does not work for me.

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
if (config.touchscreen == Configuration.TOUCHSCREEN_STYLUS)
    Toast.makeText(this, "TOUCHSCREEN_STYLUS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can detect S-Pen and other stylus's pretty reliably via InputManager:

```
    boolean sPen = false;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {
        InputManager inptmgr = (InputManager)getSystemService(INPUT_SERVICE);
        int[] inputs = inptmgr.getInputDeviceIds();
        for(int i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
            if(inptmgr.getInputDevice(inputs[i]).getName().toLowerCase().contains("pen")) sPen = true;
        }
    }
```

Usually devices will register with their appropriate names contained in them, for example, "Bluetooth Mouse", "Logitech USB Keyboard" or "E_Pen"

Answer (score 3):

Here you go (from the Android documentation) - seems to only be supported in 4.0 and up though.
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html

> Android now provides APIs for receiving input from a stylus input
>   device such as a digitizer tablet peripheral or a stylus-enabled touch
>   screen.
>
> Stylus input operates in a similar manner to touch or mouse input.
>   When the stylus is in contact with the digitizer, applications receive
>   touch events just like they would when a finger is used to touch the
>   display. When the stylus is hovering above the digitizer, applications
>   receive hover events just like they would when a mouse pointer was
>   being moved across the display when no buttons are pressed.
>
> Your application can distinguish between finger, mouse, stylus and
>   eraser input by querying the “tool type" associated with each pointer
>   in a MotionEvent using *getToolType()*. The currently defined tool types
>   are: **TOOL_TYPE_UNKNOWN**, **TOOL_TYPE_FINGER**, **TOOL_TYPE_MOUSE**,
>   **TOOL_TYPE_STYLUS**, and **TOOL_TYPE_ERASER**. By querying the tool type,
>   your application can choose to handle stylus input in different ways
>   from finger or mouse input.
>
> Your application can also query which mouse or stylus buttons are
>   pressed by querying the “button state" of a MotionEvent using
>   *getButtonState()*. The currently defined button states are:
>   **BUTTON_PRIMARY**, **BUTTON_SECONDARY**, **BUTTON_TERTIARY**, **BUTTON_BACK**, and
>   **BUTTON_FORWARD**. For convenience, the back and forward mouse buttons
>   are automatically mapped to the **KEYCODE_BACK** and **KEYCODE_FORWARD** keys.
>   Your application can handle these keys to support mouse button based
>   back and forward navigation.
>
> In addition to precisely measuring the position and pressure of a
>   contact, some stylus input devices also report the distance between
>   the stylus tip and the digitizer, the stylus tilt angle, and the
>   stylus orientation angle. Your application can query this information
>   using *getAxisValue()* with the axis codes **AXIS_DISTANCE**, **AXIS_TILT**, and
>   **AXIS_ORIENTATION**.

Comment: This answers not my question.
I know that it supports the stylus after a motionevent with the TOOL_TYPE_STYLUS.

I want to know that at the start of my app.

Comment: But technically don't all devices support the stylus then as long as it's a capacitive stylus? ICS 4.0 supports the stylus officially, but I would tend to think that all devices support the capacitive stylus in general. Just my $0.02 though - makes sense to me in my head.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Aaron Gillion is looking to be working, but trusting detection of a function to a name looks non-100%-reliable.

I checked out the standard Android [`InputDevice`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice) and found out some an interesting function [`supportsSource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice#supportsSource(int)) which allows if the device supports e.g. [`SOURCE_STYLUS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice#SOURCE_STYLUS). Here an example:

```java
if (Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
    InputManager im = (InputManager) context.getSystemService(INPUT_SERVICE);
    for (int id : im.getInputDeviceIds()) {
        InputDevice inputDevice = im.getInputDevice(id);
        if (
                inputDevice.supportsSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_STYLUS) ||
                inputDevice.supportsSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_BLUETOOTH_STYLUS)
        )
            return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

If you pursue lower SDK you can inline `supportsSource` function, which is ridiculously simple:

```java
public boolean supportsSource(int source) {
    return (mSources & source) == source;
}
```

And constants:

```
added in 23 - SOURCE_BLUETOOTH_STYLUS = 0x00008000 | SOURCE_STYLUS
added in 14 - SOURCE_STYLUS = 0x00004000 | SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER
added in  9 - SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER = 0x00000002 from 9
```

I've tested the code on a couple of devices and it is detecting the stylus correctly. I would appreciated if you can share your results of detecting the stylus on non-Samsung devices.

Comment: Works on Pixelbook (ChromeOS)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any such thing as to detect stylus input. I would assume that if the device has touch capability, it can also respond to a stylus. Android doesn't specifically support stylus input, as far as I know.