# Android: detect capacitive or resistive touchscreen

Tags: android, touchscreen

Resistive touchscreens work on the basis of pressure applied to the screen.
Capacitive touchscreens work by sensing the conductive properties of the skin on your fingertip. A capacitive screen is more responsive than a resistive screen when it comes to gestures such as swiping and pinching.

Is it possible to detect the screen type programmatically?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294754/how-to-detect-if-the-screen-is-capacitive-or-resistive-in-an-android-device) from 2010 doesn't have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [`TouchScreen`](https://github.com/BhalchandraSW/android-touchscreentype/blob/master/TouchScreen.java) class that returns screen type based on [`Build.MODEL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL) using a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).